# Join Data with summarize (max) in ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, spatial-join

I want to add this process to the ModelBuilder (there are a lot of data needed to do with this step) but apparently, this is different with spatial join. I have been trying spatial join (one to one and one to many) but the result is different.

[image: here]

Comment: What does your test model for this part of your workflow look like so far?

Comment: It's a mix of numbers (Float, Long, Integer) and Text, turns out I only need to select a maximum only number to get the expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve summarize max as I asked before in ModelBuilder by using spatial join, right-clicking in all of the fields that have numbers, and selecting *merge rule* and *maximum*.

[image]